# JMeter: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" Error in Response Data

Tags: timeout, server, client, jmeter, distributed

I am trying to execute JMeter Test Plan in distributed mode however there is a connection timeout error everytime but it works when Test Plan is executed in non-distributed mode.

Help appreciated!

Below is the response data from Listener:

```html
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://URL refused
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
 ... 14 more
```

Comment: Have you checked network connectivity between jmeter master and slaves? if not try keeping all nodes in same network with firewall rules disabled.

Comment: Yes, JMeter Master and Slaves are connected. Firewalls might be the problem for this.

Comment: Yup. Try disabling them and let us know if that helps.

Comment: Sure, will let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Since connection is refused, it means a firewall has probably cut the connection.

So 2 options:

- You need to configure Enterprise proxy in JMeter as per:

  - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server
- You need to open port between JMeter and target server